# Cannot get Apache to find php5apache2_2.dll - All the solutions I have tried do not work

Tags: php, apache

I know this question has been asked many times but I have a working Apache 2.0.64 on Windows 7 and cannot get find the php5apache2_2.dll library (PHP version 5.4.5 VC9).  I have tried every solution I can find but nothing works. The Apache log says it can't find the file with "/" in the pathname regardless of whether I use "/" or "\".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load an Apache 2.2 module into Apache 2.0. That won't work -- use a more recent version of Apache and try again.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I downloaded Apache 2.2 ans still seeing the same problem.